# How to make visual studio go the location of changes when you press "undo"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've changed from visual studio 2010 express to visual studio 2013, and i don't like a few things.

But of those what I hate most is not going back to the place where I made changes previously when I press undo.

It does go to text localization on regular text addition, but if you "replace" using quick find and replace, he will not go to the place where you did replace, leaving me unsure of what I did replace.

Is it possible to change this kind of behavior?

A little extra question: I can't find the comment/uncomment commands in the tool options, I'd like them to show up on right click, is this possible too?

Comment: If you do a full Find and Replace it should open all files where a change was made.  That should solve your first problem (although no, I don't believe you can override the undo behavior).  Also, your last extra question IS an extra question, and should have a question created for it as such.

Comment: @DavidL Yes, I apologize. There are some other threads with that kind of question and I didn't want to spam the site with a barely related to programming question. Can you help me out, or should I really create another topic?

Comment: I honestly don't know the answer to your bonus question :).  My recommendation is in keeping with SO best practices and etiquette, not to mention you'll have better success in receiving an answer if it is a standalone question.  That said, it is not particularly code-related and might be better suited to a different stackexchange site.

Comment: You have to add the comment/uncomment commands. They aren't present by default (for whatever reason). Just right click on on the ribbon and edit/customize commands and they will be in there. You want the 'Text Editor' option

Comment: @mwilson What ribbon? Isn't it on Tools/Options/Customize/Context menu?

Comment: Maybe 'ribbon' was not the proper nomenclature. Just right click on the 'play' button (debug button aka green 'play' button) and you should see the option there. You should get a context menu with selectable options.